# Is MassTransit.ActiveMQ netstandard?

Tags: c#, activemq-classic, masstransit

I use MassTransit in my product. I have to use ActiveMQ. The project, where the MassTransit.ActiveMQ package is included, is targeted to the netstandard2.0. I wouldn't want to change it, but the package contains assemblies for net452 and netcoreapp2.0.

Is there any chance that the MassTransit.ActiveMQ package will support the netstandard?

Comment: If you aren't sure what a package targets, you can [check the FuGet page for it](https://www.fuget.org/packages/MassTransit.ActiveMQ), which offers far more detail than NuGet itself. Notice that the difference between checking the NuGet and FuGet page for a package is as simple as changing the domain name in the URL. If it supports netstandad, you'll see it listed [like this](https://www.fuget.org/packages/Flurl).

Answer (score 0):

Because the [ActiveMQ packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Apache.NMS.Core/) reference `netcoreapp2.0` the same is required to use it with MassTransit. Since you should only be referencing the actual transport on your main assembly, it shouldn't cause too much of an issue. You only need to reference MassTransit in your consumer/component assemblies.